# CouchDB - Replication with attachment

Tags: couchdb, replication, attachment

I want to set up replication for documents with attachment.

If I change the document but not the attachment, is that the attachment will also be pushed?
In my case I don't want.

(I use CouchDB 1.2.0)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by sniffing packets with Whireshark.

If you change a document with attachment without changing attachment itself, it will not push.